# Footer CSS problems

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm making a Wordpress Theme but I have a little problem with the footer. I want it to occupy the 100% of the window, but it only occupies 1200px. I don't know why it's shown like that. Here you have the CSS Code

```
#navigationposition {
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-origin: initial;
    background-clip: initial;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 0;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("http://www.lasvegasicc.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Las-Vegas-Wallpaper-HD.jpeg");
}
```

[Here's the link to the website](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar/)

Comment: Run your page through the validator. There are mismatches in opening and closing tags that make the footer appear to be inside the content area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div `id=#container` restraints the footer to not exceed `1200px`. This is happening here :

```
#container {
max-width: 1200px;
background-color: transparent;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can either take the content of your footer out of the container or remove `max-width:1200px` from container rule.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer is inside a `div#container` with a 1200px width.
Move out your `div#navigationposition` from the `div#container` and it should be alright ;)

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are placing this div ( navigationposition ) inside another one which has a fixed width, and is limiting your DIV. 
If you cannot access to the code that is framing yours, ( few websites don't let you change container  ) then the  only possible way I think is to make this DIV ( navigationposition ) absolute with bottom=0 ( the result wont be the same  when you scroll)
If you can haveaccess to all code, then change the width of the div that contains the div ( navigationposition )

```
/*if you can change it*/

#container {
  /*width:1200px;*/
  width:100%;
}

  /*Only if you cannot change its container*/

#navigationposition {
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
  /*position:relative;*/
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-origin: initial;
  background-clip: initial;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("http://www.lasvegasicc.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Las-Vegas-Wallpaper-HD.jpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use position absolute and height:100vh. it seems done with this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).